# What is the best kind of grass/seed for a completely shaded lawn?

Tags: lawn, grass

After our home was built this winter, we had a new lawn seeded in the spring and it came in nicely almost everywhere except one area in the back that is in the shade all day long (there are woods on one side and the house on the other).

I plan to add additional seed to that area of the lawn but want to choose a type of grass that will do ok with almost no direct sunlight if there is such a thing.

What do you suggest?

Edit: I live near Madison, Wisconsin.

Comment: There is [a discussion on Meta on whether this question belongs in the scope of this site](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/128/should-general-questions-on-lawn-maintenance-be-considered-on-topic). Please let us know your opinion!

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you said where you are. However, if you're in the southern US, Saint Augustine would be a good choice. If you're in a cooler climate some types of Fescue might work for you. Another thing to consider would be a ground cover - perhaps Jasmine.